# Best practice for initialization code in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have some initialization code that needs to be run when my Java Swing application starts, without any events being triggered.

My initialization code is in the `myInits()` function. `myInits()` does all sorts of thing: reads config from a file, sets the background and some labels, spawns network threads, initializes variables.

From googling and my own knowledge i have figured out different ways to achieve this(please correct me if any of the assumptions stated below are wrong):

1. Run `myInits()` when the `Window_Opened` event is triggered.

This makes sure the GUI is painted and `myInits()` can access any component and change it. Unfortunately I can't use this method because my application starts hidden and `Window_Opened` doesn't get triggered.

---

2. Put `myInits()` inside the `JFrame` constructor:

   ```
   public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

       private MyFrame(){

           initComponents();  // <= Auto generated by NetBeans GUI Builder

           myInits();

       }
   }
   ```

I suppose there's nothing wrong with this methoed because `initComponents()` itself does all kinds of GUI manipulation. I used this method and it worked just fine.

But today I changed `MyFrame` into a Singleton and i got a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`. Because `myInits()` calls `MyFrame.getInstance()` and by putting it in the constructor I'm technically calling `getInstance()` inside another `getInstance()`. I tried making `getInstance()` `synchronized` but it didn't work.

---

3. Make `myInits()` `public` and call it from  `main()` :

   ```
   public static void main(String args[]) {

       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               new ChatFrame().myInits();
           }
       });
   }
   ```

I personally don't like this method because i don't want `myInits()` to be `public`. Also because I like number 4 better.

---

4. `invokeLater` `myInits()` in the constructor.

   ```
   private myFrame(){

       initComponents();

       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run(){
               myInits();
           }
       });


   }
   ```

This is what i myself came up with. Because the instantiation itself is being done in an `invokeLater()` method(see number 3), I figured I could be sure that `myInits()` will run after `new myFrame();` has finished and i can safely call `MyFrame.getInstance()`.

---

To sum it up:

1) Are all of these methods correct?

2) Is any of these (or other possible methods i may have not mentioned) considered the best practice?

3) Which one is the best practice for a Singleton JFrame?

4) Why when i `synchronized` my `getInstance()` method i still got the `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`?

Comment: Normally, singletons do not have a public constructor.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. They are private in my code. I fixed it here.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if your initialization logic in not ui specific, it should be in main. Extract a separate class out of myinit, and call it in main.

You may also make it singleton using enum, and use it, so that it gets initialized upon first use/ application load.

Comment: The initialization code for a class should be in a constructor, not main. If the code can be extracted to a method, there is no reason not to do so because it makes the constructor block smaller.

Comment: It depends upon what he is trying to init. If he is Trina to init application in the frame/window initialization, it's more troublesome than having a static call in main.

Comment: Or actually we should have an application class that does all the initializations, and then renders the view

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the content of `myInits`

Comment: myInits() is too big to post here. What it does is initializing some variables, reading configuration from a file, changing some GUI elements like icons and labels, adding custom event listeners to GUI elements, spawning threads to scan the network.

Comment: Split myInits() into at least two parts.  All the non-GUI stuff, which can run on any Thread either before or after your Frame exists, and any GUI stuff.